# Reaching yaml consul config from Spring-Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, consul, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

I try to use Consul as configuration server with Spring boot. I already succeed to use the kv store of consul to fetch variables, but now I want to be able to fetch variables as YAML files. Here is my bootstrap.yaml :

```
spring:
  cloud.consul:
    host: localhost
    port: 8500
    config:
      enabled: true
      format: YAML
      failFast: true
```

I put this config on consul on the path "/config/my.application.name/data" :

```
testspring: hello
```

And I try to reach this property using :

```
@Value("${testspring}")
```

... with no success.
What am I missing here ? What is the good path for config on consul ?

Thanks

EDIT :
It appears that the config is loaded on the value ${data} and that it is not parsed. The data="testspring: hello", which is not what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fetch data using your sample. But if I remove `format: YAML` (so use default KEY_VALUE) from my config then not parsed `data` property is fetched.
Maybe double check your `bootstrap.yml` config for correct indentations.

What version of Spring Boot and Spring Cloud you are using ?